# how to modify the value without updating it and then matching it with the element in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have an element which whose value I am getting dynamically to match.
The only difference is the value in DB is concatenated with an underscore and the value I am getting is without underscore. So is there any way to modify the value according to what I am getting and apply "find".

Collection:

```
    "name": {
      "age": 23,
      "firstname": "sweta",
      "secondname": "sharma"},
      "hobbyImages": [
         0: "0_abc_0.jpg",
         1: "1_def_1.jpg"
      ]
    }
```

Query:

```
db.find({ "name.age": 23, "hobbyImages": imageName });
```

I am having an image name as `abc.jpg`

Expected Result:

The collection which I have mentioned above but I am not getting anything.
Does anyone have any idea how to remove the '_' and '0' and then check the element value?

Comment: is the structure of image string always `<number>_<image_name>_<number>.<image_type>`?

Comment: @Ravi Shankar Bharti it is always like that

Answer (score 1):

You can try match the image with `$regex`.

```
const [name, ex] = imageName.split('.');
const regex = new RegExp(`\\d_${name}_\\d.${ex}`, "gi")
db.users.find(
   { "name.age": 23, "hobbyImages": { "$elemMatch": { "$regex": regex } } }
)
```

Comment: @Vassilis Pallas i dont have this content with me "gi".
I only have "abc.jpg"

Comment: what does "gi" mean in $options ? I have not heard of "g" in the options.

Comment: It's the global match modifier. Find all matches rather than stopping after the first match.

Comment: @Felipe Sulser  can i have an example?

Comment: I edit my answer. The `i` is insensitive. `g` is global (not to stop on the first match)

Comment: I'm glad I helped!